# How to finish one Activity and go to specify fragment in the another activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

**EDIT:**
Hi.
I have **MainActivity** on which I open **Fragment A** with:

```
fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.db_container, Fragment A);
fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

This fragment uses `LiveData` and shows `RecyclerView` list.
Then after user select some category I open Fragment B with:

```
fragmentTransaction.hide(Fragment A);
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.db_container, Fragment B);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

This fragment also uses `LiveData` and shows `RecyclerView` list.
When the user selects a single item and wants to edit it, they is moved to **EditItem Activity**.
After user do some changes and saved it, the activity ends with the command: **finish();**
User back to **Fragment B** and `RecyclerView` list is updated.
The problem is that before the list of **fragment B** is updated, the list in **fragment A** is updated first.
Exactly code in Fragment A:

```
item_viewmodel.getAllCategoryModel().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<Items>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<Items> myLists) {
            // Here the code is executed first before updating the list in fragment B.
        }
    });
```

So the question is.
How to only update list in **Fragment B** ?
Later from **fragment B** I will update list in **Fragment A** manually, using `interface` callback.
Optionally I want to update the List in **Fragment B** as first then list in **Fragment A**.
If it possible I don't want to remove **fragment A**, only hide it.

Comment: Your question is highly unclear and thus you should format it better and make it more clearer, otherwise people will ignore it - Just a suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand that you want to update fragment B only and then manually update fragment A.
I assume that the data you are using in your lists is shared between fragment A and B, and thats why fragment A is updated because A and B have observers on same objects.
You can use a boolean variable in A `boolean shouldUpdate = true;`
and make it false when you move to B.
Also inside you observer in A do check `if(shouldUpdate)` .

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. I have two more questions.
1. Whether the boolean value can be static or I must use interface to communicate between fragments?
2. You said "and thats why fragment A is updated because A and B have observers on same objects." I don't understand. How to find out that both fragments have observers on same object.? I register item_viewmodel...observe in both fragments, so what it depends on?

Comment: LiveData wraps a value to observe it state so whenever the value is changed the observer will be triggered.So if you have multiple observers on same value all of them will be triggered when it changes even if they are in diffrent fragments.

Comment: Oh. Thanks you for explanation. Returning for the first question, boolean variable can be static? Or better I should use interface?

Comment: It's up to your need and design, I would personally recommend using interface to keep things clean up.

Comment: Ok. Sorry for many questions. Last my question: How to trigger "onChange" method manually? (I mean this method which I asked in main question) I can refer to the variable item_viewmodel. but after dot I don't know what to "say" to system to repeat onChange method one more time.

Comment: Never mind I made another topic for question above. Thanks for time and explanations :) Your answer works.